# find master key given all but last decryption round keys

Tags: aes

I have all but the last round key in AES-256 CBC decryption, and would like to build the master key, but I am unsure how to go about it.

I have read I can convert decryption roundkeys to encryption roundkeys via forward MixColumns. Then perhaps xor key n-3, n-2 to get n-1 (one i need). Does S-box substitution come into play here?

Or is there a keyschedule generator based on decryption roundkeys rather than encryption... thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How secure is the AES master key if Round Keys are found](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15200/how-secure-is-the-aes-master-key-if-round-keys-are-found) also [How does the key schedule of Rijndael looks for keysizes other than 128 bit?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2486/18298)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a non-standard version of AES decryption, the decryption round keys should just be the encryption round keys in reverse order. In the notation of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_key_schedule#The_key_schedule), it sounds like you have $W_4,\ldots,W_{59}$ and you want to know $W_0,\ldots, W_7$ ($W_4,\ldots W_7$ represent the penultimate decryption round key; $W_8,\ldots W_{11}$ represent the antepenultimate decryption round key and so forth).

$W_4,\ldots W_7$ can be read off directly and (per the linked article) we have
$$W_8=W_0\oplus S(\mathrm{LeftShift}(W_7)\oplus 1\iff W_0=W_8\oplus S(\mathrm{LeftShift}(W_7))\oplus 1$$
and
$$W_9=W_1\oplus W_8\iff W_1=W_9\oplus W_8$$
$$W_{10}=W_2\oplus W_9\iff W_2=W_{10}\oplus W_9$$
$$W_{11}=W_3\oplus W_{10}\iff W_3=W_{11}\oplus W_{10}$$
which allows us to recover $W_0,\ldots,W_7$ which is the same as $K_0,\ldots, K_7$.

Note that the LeftShift function rotates the 32-bit word left by 8 bits and that the [$S$-box is the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Forward_S-box) as used in AES encryption.

ETA if you are using the "T-table" implementation of AES (which is suggested by your MixCol remark), then yes, you will need to apply MixCol to the 32-bit words to get the $W_i$. If you use the standard AES MixCol() then no S-box adjustment is needed; if you use the T-table combined MixCol(Subbytes()) then you'll also need to apply the Inverse S-box as well.